# Why is NgbModal throwing error on close/dismiss?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, popup, bootstrap-modal

I am using NgbModal. When I click x or close, which calls this.activeModal.close() or this.activeModal.dismiss() it throws me this error:

```
ReportProblemDialogComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
at NgbModalRef._removeModalElements (modal-ref.js?5ad7:114)
at NgbModalRef.dismiss (modal-ref.js?5ad7:108)
at NgbActiveModal.activeModal.dismiss (modal-stack.js?0971:36)
at ReportProblemDialogComponent.ngOnDestroy (report-problem-dialog.component.ts?631e:150)
at callProviderLifecycles (core.js?593e:12697)
at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js?593e:12658)
at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js?593e:12641)
at destroyView (core.js?593e:14007)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js?593e:15041)
at Object.debugDestroyView [as destroyView] (core.js?593e:14592)
```

After reloading component, it still stays open and after redirection to another page, it is showing. How to close NgbModal?

This is my service for opening modal:

```
open(component: Component): Promise<NgbModalRef> {

    return new Promise<NgbModalRef>((resolve, reject) => {
        const isOpen = this.ngbModalRef !== null;
        if (isOpen) {
            resolve(this.ngbModalRef);
        }
        // setTimeout used as a workaround for getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.ngbModalRef = this.reportProblemModalRef(component, new Object());
            resolve(this.ngbModalRef);
        }, 0);

    });
}

reportProblemModalRef(component: Component, ticket: any): NgbModalRef {

    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(component, { size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static'});
    modalRef.componentInstance.ticket = ticket;
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: null }}], { replaceUrl: true, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
        this.ngbModalRef = null;
    }, (reason) => {
        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: null }}], { replaceUrl: true, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
        this.ngbModalRef = null;
    });
    return modalRef;
}
```

Comment: You should reproduce the issue on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: seem the problem is with the parent of removeChild. where are you using this in your code?

Comment: I am using it in ReportProblemPopupService